# Image used on a plane does not line up when using an array modifier

Tags: modifiers

I have a simple brick road with yellow traffic line divider. When I apply the array modifier and line up the traffic lines at the default relative offset parameters, the road lines up but the traffic lines do not. When I align the traffic lines at Y relative offset .011 , the road itself becomes misaligned. [image: Traffic lines]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use the tools in this site to make the images part of the question. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions to learn how to do it.

Comment: use array and curve modifier

Comment: Maybe your mesh is a bit crooked relative to your object.

Comment: It's a simple plane, with no subdivisions. Thanks.

Comment: Will try curve modifier. Did not do it earlier because it was just a straight road which is away from the main components of my scene. Thanks.

Comment: Curve modifier did the trick. Thanks ateks.

Comment: @mrfrisky if you solved your problem, please write an answer to your own question. (read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by ateks, a curve modifier did the trick. In order to keep it straight, I just extended the curve, nurbspath, on x axis (g-x), then applied the modifier to the road section. Then applied the array modifier to lock it all in.